# How to add Active Directory user group as login in Tabular Model Database in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-permissions, tabular

I need to give a 'Active Directory User Group' read access to a tabular model database. I am not able to find the group when searched, to add it to a role.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029014/how-to-add-active-directory-user-group-as-login-in-sql-server) for a database instance, adding the group to 'Logins' in 'Security' Folder is the first step. But 'Security' folder is not there in case of tabular model as shown in screen shot below. First one out of 3 is Tabular Model instance:

[image: The first instance shows tabular model]
<sub>(source: [sqlmusings.com](http://www.sqlmusings.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Different-SSAS-Models-in-SSMS.png))</sub>

I am admin for the server if that would be required. How to give 'Active Directory User Group' read access to a tabular model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there must be a role defined in the Tabular model.  Then you add the active directory group to the list of members.  If the model was developed/deployed from a system that doesn't have access to the domain, then the group will have to be added after the fact.  This can be done via SSMS...

Navigate to the roles folder:

```
<SSAS Tabular Instance> | Databases | <tabular model> | Roles
```

- Right-click the role to which you want to add the active directory
  group
- Select the Membership page
- Click Add

...at this point, make sure the correct objects are selected (users, groups, etc), and locations (network, domains, etc)...this window is pretty standard in windows apps.

[image]