# Login exception for application connecting to SQL using Windows authentication

Tags: sql, vb.net

We have a situation where we have a Windows Application connecting to SQL Server using Windows Authentication (similar to [How to add Active Directory user group as login in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029014/how-to-add-active-directory-user-group-as-login-in-sql-server)). All the Active Directory users who will be using the application have been added to an AD group (let's call it GroupX)

A login was then created on the SQL instance for GroupX. Only the "public" server role has been assigned to this login. On the database itself a user was created for GroupX. The "db_Owner" role permission was allocated to the this group user. We need "db_Owner" permissions as the application needs read/write access as well as permission to do schema changes.

When the desktop application attempts to connect to the database we get an exception: "Cannot open database z requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user y.

The area of SQL Security is a bit new to me as I am used to being a sysadmin on my own SQL instance against which I develop and off course in that kind of environment everything just works.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess this issue never made any progress?  I have the same problem and can't lick it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ensure that the db_owner permission shows up for the user group in the database?

> Go to SQL Server >> Security >> Logins and right click on Group X and select Properties
>
> In newly opened screen of Login Properties, go to the “User Mapping”
>   tab. Then, on the “User Mapping” tab, select the desired database –
>   especially the database for which this error message is displayed. On
>   the lower screen, check the role db_owner. Click OK.

Source: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/

Comment: Change `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` to `GroupX` and this would be a good approach to see if the users is mapped correctly.

Comment: @JodyT Thanks! Done. I just copied the soltution from the link, and didn't think of updating it.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. I have checked now under User Mappings for the login and can confirm that "db_owner" is indeed selected as well as "public". I have also checked the properties of the "public" server role now to make sure that Connect permissions have not been revoked for this role. One thing I have noticed however is that the properties window from the client only shows Endpoints whereras on my machine there is a node for Servers as well. The only way for users to currently connect to the databases is to give the Group sysadmin privileges which does not make sense.