# SQL Server Mgmt Studio Creating New Login No Group

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm using SSMS 2016 from a Windows 7 Pro machine. When I right click on Logins (under Security) I do not see a choice for Group as can be seen here:

[How to add Active Directory user group as login in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029014/how-to-add-active-directory-user-group-as-login-in-sql-server)

This is for AD users.

RON

Comment: Hi Ron, what version of SQL Server are you logged into?

Comment: Have you tried the raw T-SQL (`create login [domain\group name] from windows`)? If so, is there an error?