# Assign read only access to windows domain group

Tags: sql-server

I have a windows domain group. Inside this group I have 3 windows users that will have access to sql server 2014.
How can I give read only access to specific database for this group?

Comment: Check this out http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/how-do-i-assign-an-entire-active-directory-group-security-access-in-sql-server-2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029014/how-to-add-active-directory-user-group-as-login-in-sql-server