# Connect Local SQL Server Database using Azure Active Directory Credentials

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory, sql-server-authentication

The SQL Server (version 2016) is located in the local Virtual Machine(Windows Server 2012 R2) and I need to provide authentication for the users in the Azure Active Directory. As I am new to this I am not even sure whether it is possible or not. Can anybody guide me.

Comment: If you want to Azure Active Directory Authentication, you could select Azure SQL database(Paas).Currently, local sql server does not support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is impossible. Please refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure).

> Connecting to SQL Server running on an Azure VM is not supported using
>   an Azure Active Directory account. Use a domain Active Directory
>   account instead.

It means if your local sql server could not use Azure Active Directory Authentication. You could use local domain Active Directory users.

If you use Azure SQL Database and SQL Data Warehouse, you could use Azure Active Directory authentication. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#provision-an-azure-active-directory-administrator-for-your-azure-sql-server).

[image]

Comment: But my SQL Server is not in the Cloud its in local system. the Server name is like **Domain name\instance name**

Comment: If it is, you could not use Azure AD user to login your sql server. Currently, Azure does not support this.

Comment: Okey then , What about the Local AD ??

Comment: You could use local AD user.

Comment: Can you please provide me the right steps to do it as I am new to the integration. And for the local AD users I want to provide SQL Server Authentication not Window Authentication if possible

Comment: Maybe you could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029014/how-to-add-active-directory-user-group-as-login-in-sql-server).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160682/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-zionz).