# Set up SQL Server to be accessible by all computers on a network via program manipulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

I am testing a SQL Server for my company as an on-site database for manufacturing data and records. I have the SQL Server on my laptop and have set up permissions and downloaded SQL Server Management Studio on other computers in the company and managed to connect via SQL Server authentication.

However, I can't get Windows Authentication to work. I also have a Visual Basic program that I can run on my laptop that will communicate with the SQL Server that is locally on my machine but that program will not work on other computers in the company because they can not connect to the SQL Server.

How do I set up SQL Server to allow for Windows authentication on any company computers running that program? I opened a port on my Windows firewall on the computer that has SQL Server installed, and it seems to work with SQL Server authentication.

The connection string I am using in my Visual Basic program is as follows:

```vb
Dim connstring As String = "Data Source = Server; integrated security = true"
```

I assume I need to change something in my logins folder in my SQL Server?

My desired result would be for any computer running this application to be allowed to communicate with SQL Server and be able to read and write data.

Comment: Create login and users on SQL server and use that credentials to connect via SQL authentication.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn This would require me to add credentials for over 100 users. I assume there is a way to use credentials set by the IT department to allow access.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I will give that a shot. Thanks Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> any computer running this application to be allowed to communicate with SQL Server

The normal configuration to enable this is:

1) The SQL Server must be running on a server joined to the domain.

2) The SQL Server is configured to use TCP/IP and listen on port 1433.

3) The other computers are also joined to the domain.

4) The users logged in on the other computers are added as Windows logins. in SQL Server, and mapped to users in the desired databases (can use groups instead of individual users).

See eg: [How to add Active Directory user group as login in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029014/how-to-add-active-directory-user-group-as-login-in-sql-server)

Comment: Just to make sure I am correct with all of this. 1) my computer is on our internal network, so it is joined to the domain. 2) TCP/IP are both set up on port 1433 and I have the local firewall set up to allow access on this port. 3) all computers are also on the internal network. 4)Can you explain the groups to me or shoot me a link to look into this further?