# How can I link a SQL Server on Windows Server to a SQL Server on Window 10?

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, linked-server

I need to know some information if anyone can help because I'm new to this.

I need to link a SQL Server running on Windows Server 2016 to another SQL Server on Windows 10. But I have no clue what tips I need to follow.

I created an Active Directory on the Windows Server, but do I need to add my Windows client to my domain before starting the process of creating linked server?

I'm so confused; I know this is just the basics but I hope anyone can help with the tips I should follow

Comment: This is a question for https://dba.stackexchange.com/, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you have the databases communicating on the backend. Do they replicate to each other, is one for read and one for write? Generally yes, you do want to have the SQL server joined to the domain if you plan to use AD as a method of authentication. Although in most cases not required I would just join the server to AD anyways and then add a login for the AD user in whatever DB they need access to. Use the link below to add AD users/groups to your SQL server.

Link: [How to add Active Directory user group as login in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029014/how-to-add-active-directory-user-group-as-login-in-sql-server)