# azure sql server row level security with ad users

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, row-level-security

Is it possible to somehow have Azure SQL Server automatically use ad users (in row level security) without always creating a login, or automatically creating a login for every user of an ad group?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Active Directory user group as login in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029014/how-to-add-active-directory-user-group-as-login-in-sql-server) I believe Azure is a similar procedure

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[Configure Azure AD authentication for Azure SQL Database](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6751/azure-ad-authentication-azure-sql-databases/)