# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Permissions

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, ssms

Our software requires the business users (of the software) to have read and write access to the database (MS SQL Server).  The users are added to an active directory group with this SQL permission.  The business users also want to query the database as read only in SQL Server Management Studio.  Is there a way that the user can have read write access to the database from the software and read only from the back end in SQL Server Management studio?

Comment: Stack Overflow is really only for programming questions. This question is a better fit for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com). That said, the answer is no. Permissions are assigned to credentials, regardless of how you access the database. Usually applications use only one account to access the database, then limit what data is shown based on the user logged in. It's not common for an application to use the user's account to access the database.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029014/how-to-add-active-directory-user-group-as-login-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the SQL server permissions are assigned to the Active Directory group, the users in the group will be able to have the same permissions irrespective of from where they are accessing the database (from the software or MS SQL server management studio)

The permissions cannot be changed based on from where the users are accessing the database